# What is the equivalent to CopyMemory in Android FMX?

Tags: android, delphi, winapi, firemonkey

I use a unit to encrypt strings with RC4 when using VCL 2006. Now I tryed to use that unit in an Android project with XE8 but I receive an error, function `CopyMemory` not found.

It seems that `Windows` library is no longer present in XE8 and I can't find it's substitute. I googled it and found `WinApi.Windows` but XE8 is not finding it.

Can I use this function in Android? What should I do if I can't. Is there a RC4 library that doesn't access memory directly?

Comment: FWIW, When you're using a multi-platform framework, you're bound to using complete namespace prefixes. As to why `WinApi.Windows` is not found, it should be there. In what way is XE8 not finding it? **EDIT** Actually you appear to be using Windows under Android. That's simply not allowed, WinApi isn't on Android. That wraps a Windows API only. The real question is what's the Android equivalent.

Comment: You can't use the `Winapi.Windows` unit on the Android platform.  It only works on the Windows platform.  Use Delphi's built-in `Move()` function instead.

Comment: The Windows library is in fact in XE8, but it's only useful on the **Windows** platform (that's why it's called **Windows**, and has been moved into the `WinAPI` namespace. You can't use Windows-only functions on Android, because (clearly) *Android is not WIndows*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent RTL function is [`System.Move`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Move).

Comment: Can it be used in Android? I tryed the library but my app freezes. I'm still cheking the issue.

Comment: Sure it works in Android. The problem is the calling code.

Comment: I wish I knew also what's wrong with my question, to be down-voted. It is a true technical doubt and it was answered.

Comment: Who knows. Nothing much you can do about it.